# vb.net mysql transactions rollback failure in multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, vb.net, transactions

I am developing pos application and struggling a few months with transaction issue with mysql inserts.some times master table data is stored and details table is rolled back inserting data in multiple tables(master-details).i have given the code below please anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
    Dim tr As MySqlTransaction
    Try
                   tr = con.BeginTransaction
                   Dim recordcount As Integer = 0
                   For i = 0 To Datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1
                            netamount = netamount + Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvNetamount").Value
                    qty = qty + Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvQty").Value
                    tax = tax + Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvTaxamount").Value
                    cm = New MySqlCommand("billing_save", con, tr)
                    cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tablename", "sale_bill")
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", "INSERT")
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRObillno", txtBillno.Text.Trim)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRObillprice", Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvRate").Value)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROqty", Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvQty").Value)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAuto_id", 0)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROdiscountpercentage", Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvDiscountPercentage").Value)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROdiscount", Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvDiscountamt").Value)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROsgst", Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvTax").Value)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROcgst", Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("dgvCGST").Value)
                  recordcount += cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
               Next
            'summary of billing
                cm = New MySqlCommand("billing_summary_save", con, tr)
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tablename", "sale_bill")
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", dgCustomer.Rows(0).Cells("dgvCustomerId").Value)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", "INSERT")
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PBillno", txtBillno.Text.Trim)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billdate", Format(dtBillDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billstatus", cmbMop.SelectedIndex)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", txtOrderNo.Text)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentdate", Format(dtBillDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                'update billno
                cm = New MySqlCommand("update bno set billno='" & billno & "'", con, tr)
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        tr.Rollback()
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cm.Dispose()
        ad.Dispose()
        tr.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Please see the code

Comment: Please i need your help i have given sample code here